# how to call helper method in collection_select tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

i wanna  call a helper method in collection select which receive name and perform some action and return this output

```
<%= collection_select :cust_alert,:alert_id, @alerts, :id, :name,:prompt => true %>
```

and my helper method is

```
def show_alert_name
@name = @alerts.collect{|alert| alert.name.html_safe }

end
```

what kind of change i need to do here i am passing array of object so i can not use select tag. or is there any other way to do this same work

Comment: What is it that you're trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: i wanna call this show_alert_name methods in my collection_select so i can remove special character from my string

Comment: Ah, I confused `collect` with `inject` for a moment. So, what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
<%= select :cust_alert,
           :alert_id,
           @alerts.map { |alert| [alert.name.html_safe, alert.id] },
           {:prompt => true} %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider using select http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html